# Aspect ratio of video responding to height is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I've been searching for an answer for this problem for too long but no such luck!

I want to be able to embed a YouTube video, and if the viewport changes either in height or width the video will change in size whilst keeping the correct aspect ratio, is this possible?

I'm aware of other solutions such as fit vid and the padding-bottom method, but none of these recalculate the aspect ratio if the height of the viewport was to change.

Any ideas welcome, js or css...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.

Using JavaScript, detect the viewport dimensions and video dimensions (and aspect ratio) during init() as a baseline. While you're there, set up a handler for the window.onorientationchange event (which will pick up resizes).

In your handler, which axis has changed size. Resize your video (retaining the original aspect ratio) to fit within that dimension, and doublecheck to be sure the other axis isn't now oversized.
If it is, resize it a second time.